# Vuex: How can I pass a variable to a getter?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

In a vue app I get an `elementId` from the URL to pass in to a vuex getter:

```
<template>
  <p>elementId: {{ elementId }}</p>
  <p>loadedElement: {{ loadedElement }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elementId: this.$route.params.id,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    loadedElement() {
      return this.$store.getters.getElementById(this.elementId);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Getter:

```
getElementById: (state) => (id) => {
  return state.elements.find(ele => ele.id === id)
},
```

Right now the page gets rendered like this:

[image]

However, when hardcode an `elementId`, it works:

```
<template>
  <p>elementId: {{ elementId }}</p>
  <p>loadedElement: {{ loadedElement }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elementId: 3,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    loadedElement() {
      return this.$store.getters.getElementById(this.elementId);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since getting the `elementId` from the route seems to work, but it is not passed into the getter function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `this.$route.params.elementId` is a string but your element IDs are numbers. Using `===` to compare a string and number will not match.

Try using `==` instead, or converting `this.$route.params.elementId` to a number:

```js
data() {
  return {
    elementId: +this.$route.params.id,
  };
},
```

(Of course, maybe you want to do more error checking as part of this.)

Comment: Thanks, that was it!
I followed this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ4zmFy4d7Y&ab_channel=Academind) where === is used. I guess I missed something there. Cheers!